# How to define type of decorator to prevent losing type info of decorated function?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Given the following:

```
// @flow

function a(s: string): ?string {
  return s === '' ? null : s
}

function decorate(f: Function): Function {
  return f
}

const b = decorate(a)

a(12)
b(12)
```

flow throws an error when you call a with a number, but not when you call b with a number

```
13: a(12)
      ^^ number. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
 3: function a(s: string): ?string {
                  ^^^^^^ string
```

Is there such a way that you can do something like

```
function decorate(f: Function): typeof(f) {
  return f
}
```

such that the decorated function typechecks properly without explicitly restricting what decorate returns like

```
function decorate(f: Function): (string) => ?string {}
```

or duplicating the type info on b like

```
const b: typeof(a) = decorate(a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make function [polymorphic](https://flowtype.org/docs/functions.html#polymorphic-functions) for this:

```
function decorate<T: Function>(f: T): T {
  return f
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parameterize your function:

```
function decorate(f: Function): Function {
  return f;
}
```

can be

```
function decorate<T>(f: T): T {
  return f;
}
```

to say "the type of the result is the same type as the input.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You guys pretty much answered simultaneously, but @vkurchatkin showed that I can specialize the parameterization with `<T: Function>` such that it can only be a function and nothing else so I picked that one.

Comment: No problem. I left it out since you never said what you needed to do with the function :)